# Java statement can't execute my query

Tags: java, sql-server, insert, odbc

I have a problem when I try to execute my query in Java. when I try to add an object to my database in SQL, it gives me a error saying that the instruction don't send the result set. When I execute the query in sql server, it work fine and it insert the object. Please help me.

```
public void addAlbum(String title, double price, String genre, String date, String home, String image) {

int number = getData().size();

boolean isThere = false;    

Statement statement;

for(int i = 0; i < getData().size();i++){

    if(getData().get(i).getTitle().equals(title)){

        isThere = true;

    }

}

if(!isThere){

    try{


        statement = connexion.createStatement();
        String query = "use albums INSERT INTO dbo.Album(Album.artist_number, title, price, genre, date, home, image) VALUES(" + number + ", '" + title + "', " + price + ", '" + genre + "', '" + date + "', '" + home + "', '" + image + "')";

        statement.executeQuery(query);

        getData().add(new Album(String.valueOf(number),title, price, genre, date, home));

        fireTableRowsInserted(getData().size() -1, getData().size() -1);

    }catch(SQLException e){

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                "Error "
                        + e.getMessage(), "Result",
                JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);

    }       


}else{

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
            "There is already an album with this name", "Result",
            JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);

}
}
```

Comment: You have a SQL injection vulnerability.

Comment: use albums INSERT INTO probably is probably not valid without a semicolon, and very well may not work with one.  Normally you would not have a use DBNAME statement, that would be part of your connection string. Also you have SQL injection Bobby O'Tables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [`Statement.executeUpdate(String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#executeUpdate%28java.lang.String%29) for `INSERT`. [`Statement.executeQuery(String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#executeQuery%28java.lang.String%29) is for `SELECT`.

`PreparedStatement`s are better, easier and safer. [Using Prepared Statements](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html).

Comment: And avoid mixing your UI code with DB code! Try using a design pattern such as Model-View-Controller